# Gradle release plugin compatible with kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, gradle-release-plugin

I'm trying to find a gradle release plugin for my kotlin spring project but all the plugins I found on out there, are quite old and not maintained for a while so they don't really work with `Kotlin DSL`.

I used the `axion` one, it worked somehow but it has issues with the CI integration and the issue was not fixed yet so I'm looking for alternatives.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my experience, If you're using CI and using a versioning system with tags (such as git), it's super trivial to release, so you don't need a plugin for it, you can just pull the version from git, add -SNAPSHOT if needed and just run publish, passing the version on the command line (not putting it anywhere in the source files).

Comment: I need it to remove the snapshot, tag the commit and prepare for next release by incrementing the version (depending on the branch) and adding snapshot, release rc versions or final versions or snapshot versions. why to do all of this manually if there are plugins to do that with a lot of flexible configuration